# Django accidentally added default value to PK

Tags: django

I accidentally set the default value for a PK.
It was when I was trying to change from default `id` to `scheduleId` by adding
a AutoField to it. But it ask me to add a default and i input 0. Now I still get the error even after the table is deleted.

How can I fix it?

Code (before):

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Code (after):

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    scheduleId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Error:

multiple default values specified for column "scheduleId" of table "customuser_schedule"

Error log:

```
File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "scheduleId" of table "customuser_schedule"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 421, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 117, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\cherngyorng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "scheduleId" of table "customuser_schedule"
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in migration folder and create a new **init**.py and rerun makemigration>migrate